# How can I change the bar colors and the legend of a ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My problem is that I use these two commands for essential changes on my plot:

```
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("A", "B")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E33V19", "#AD4H48"))
```

Apparently, I can't do that because they cancel each other out.

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding
another scale for 'fill', which will replace the
existing scale.
```

The first line is to change the label of my legend from default names to Auto and Import and the second line is to change the colors of the bars.
Two independent commands. How can I make use of both without having an error by r?

Comment: Right, you can only set one scale per aesthetic, the two override one another. Why are you *trying to* set two contradictory scales? Just leave off the (automatically coloured) discrete scale, and assign labels in the manual scale call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both arguments in `scale_fill_manual`.

Here's an example:

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(43,32,41,44),
                  col2 = c(21,31,12,23),
                  col3 = c("a","a","d","d"))
  col1 col2 col3
1   43   21    a
2   32   31    a
3   41   12    d
4   44   23    d
```

Code:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = col2,y= col1, fill = col3)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F93B19", "#AB9B98"),
                    labels = c("Auto","Import"))
```

Output:
[image: Export]